# Beamer \pause command help

Tags: beamer, pause

I am using Beamer class and I need to load an image in the slide when a particular text(itemize element) is visible but I don't know how to do it with \pause[number]. MWE is given below with standard preamble settings.

```
\begin{frame}{Overview of Existing Multiple Access Schemes}\pause
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Existing Multiple Access Schemes\pause
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item FDMA\pause
                    \item TDMA\pause
                    \item CDMA\pause
                    \item OFDMA
                \end{itemize}
            \column{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item FDMA-Image\pause
                    \item TDMA-Image\pause
                    \item CDMA-Image\pause
                    \item OFDMA-Image
                \end{itemize}
        \end{columns}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I need to load FDMA-Image when FDMA is become visible in the presentation and followed by the rest of items in the list i.e. TDMA, CDMA, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onslide` and its abbrevs. You will learn much more reading beamer documentation chapter dedicated to overlays (`texdoc beamer` with texlive).

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview of Existing Multiple Access Schemes}
   \begin{itemize}
       \item Existing Multiple Access Schemes      
        \begin{columns}[c]
           \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
              \begin{itemize}
                 \item<1-> FDMA
                 \item<2-> TDMA
                 \item<3-> CDMA
                 \item<4-> OFDMA
             \end{itemize}
           \end{column}
           \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item<1-> FDMA-Image
                \item<2-> TDMA-Image
                \item<3-> CDMA-Image
                \item<4-> OFDMA-Image
             \end{itemize}
           \end{column}
        \end{columns}
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I'd bet you will soon need `\only` and friends if you're used to designing your frames this way. Look for example, in your last column, at what happens if you replace your `itemize` environment with:

```
                \only<1> FDMA-Image
                \only<2> TDMA-Image
                \only<3> CDMA-Image
                \only<4> OFDMA-Image
```

Comment: Since you may be a new user of beamer, I added some suggestions. Note btw that this kind of issue has certainly already been solved somewhere in TEX S.E.